# $.ajax calls working, but backbone fetch and save are not working

Tags: ajax, backbone.js

I have a backbone app where any $.ajax() call I make to the PHP API works great and returns successful on a GET or POST request. However, when I try a model.fetch() or model.save() call (using the same endpoint), I am returned with:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://xyz.com.
Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

I know that's not much to go off of, but would there be a reason that backbone's ajax calls would be returning with errors, but when converted to just plain ajax calls, they are successful?

The headers in my PHP-based API on the server are:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true"); 
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: origin, content-type, accept');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: OPTIONS, POST, GET, DELETE, PUT');
header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');
```

Comment: I am pretty sure you cannot do cross domain calls unless you are issuing a GET request thats returns JSONP or you are using CORS. Please post your $.ajax that you say is working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Backbone is using [Backbone.sync](http://backbonejs.org/#Sync) method to do ajax. It is doing same `jquery.ajax` with some default settings. This is the [source code](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-134) for Backbone.sync. You can match backbone's ajax setting with your ajax.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your approach. I did using fetch in the below manner. it worked fine for me. This might help you.

When you call .fetch, the model will trigger a request event, and when you receive it, parse it and set it to the model, the model will trigger a sync event.

var UserModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        url:'http://api.geonames.org/astergdemJSON?formatted=true&lat=50.01&lng=10.2&username=demo&style=full'
    });

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.model = new UserModel();
        this.listenTo(this.model,'sync', this.render);
        this.model.fetch({success:this.success,error:this.error});
    },
    render: function() {
        console.log('do awesome stuff here'+this.model.toJSON());
    },
    success:function(data){
        console.log(data.attributes.status);
    },
    error:function(data){
        console.log('error'+data.attributes.status)
    }
});

var view = new MyView();
```